# Selectize.js pre populate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selectize.js

I have the following [selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js) :

```
  $("#abc").selectize({
      valueField: 'name',
      labelField: 'name',
      searchField: ['name'],
      plugins: ['remove_button'],
      createOnBlur: true,
      maxItems: 10,
      preload: true,
      create:function (input){
        callback({ name:'Cricket', name:'Football', name : 'Tennis'})
      },
  });
```

The html code is :

`<select id="abc" name="sport[]"></select>`

I want the `Cricket`, `Football`, `Tennis` to pre load, Means it should be auto loaded on page load. **But the options are not loading, What am i missing ?**

Comment: It looks lik your `create` function is not written correctly. Read the doc: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you might just be looking for the `options` property to set the initial list of selection options and the `items` property to select the ones you want defaulted. If so, you don't need the `create` function (which is there to enable you to customize the handling of user entered options). See below.

```js
$('#abc').selectize({
  options: [
    {name: 'Cricket'},
    {name: 'Football'},
    {name: 'Tennis'}
  ],
  items: [
    'Cricket',
    'Football',
    'Tennis'
  ],
  valueField: 'name',
  labelField: 'name',
  searchField: ['name'],
  plugins: ['remove_button'],
  createOnBlur: true,
  maxItems: 10,
  preload: true
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Selectize</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input id="abc" name="abc" type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, The items are coming into the dropdown but not selected by default.

Comment: For that you need to use the `items` property. See answer edit.

Comment: Perfect, Can we parse the array into `options` and `items` ? Because that is the actual thing i need to do ?

Comment: Yes, you can handle the data anywhere you want and just use the `addOption()` and `addItem()` methods to populate the selectize control (you can also include a function in the `load` property depending on what makes sense for how you are retrieving your dataset).